# Creating a service to run at the end of a shutdown

Tags: linux, systemctl

I am implementing a service in a Linux machine which I want to run, just before my machine shuts down (every time it shuts down).
I found this documentation: https://www.mauras.ch/systemd-run-it-last.html, which I followed.

1. I created my new custom target:

cat /etc/systemd/system/custom.target

```
     [Unit]
     Description=Custom Target
     Requires=multi-user.target
     After=multi-user.target
     AllowIsolate=yes
```

2. I Created a unit file for your command

cat /etc/systemd/system/custom.target.wants/app-shutdown.service

```
[Unit]
Description=App Shutdown
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=echo 'started'
ExecStop=bash /myhome/app-shutdown.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutStopSec=480

[Install]
WantedBy=custom.target
```

3. When I try the command: systemctl list-units --type target --all

I can't see my custom.target

4. Still done other procedures:

`systemctl isolate custom.target`

`ln -sf /etc/systemd/system/custom.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target`

Now by doing systemctl list-units --type target --all I can see:
custom.target loaded active   active Custom Target

Symlink created successfully.

When I reboot the machine and try doing:
systemctl status App-Shutdown

App-Shutdown.service - App Shutdown
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/App-Shutdown.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

It's not active anymore.

Any ideas what as happened? And how can I troubleshoot this?

For some reason the command
`ln -sf /etc/systemd/system/custom.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target`
was not executed. THat was what was missing.

After that I did this:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable app-shutdown
sudo systemctl start app-shutdown
```

Rebooted and the service was active.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347306/how-to-execute-scripts-in-usr-lib-systemd-system-shutdown-at-reboot-or-shutdow https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526356/systemd-run-a-command-before-shutdown-while-network-is-still-up https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284598/systemd-how-to-execute-script-at-shutdown-only-not-at-reboot

Comment: I have those steps. I checked but I don't know why the service  becomes inactice at reboot